# Bower issue when deploying to heroku custom git module

Tags: git, heroku, bower

Running into a deployment build failure when using bower on heroku.

This is my post install step:

`gem install sass && bower install && brunch build --production`

However, bower fails to install a package specified simply by a git url and not a version.

The following package specification causes the issue.

```
"bootstrap-offcanvas": "git://github.com/yagudaev/Bootstrap-Offcanvas.git#master"
```

Heroku complains about not being able to retrieve the right revision to install the bower component. (You will have to first set 
`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose` to see it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the reversion directly to avoid revision resolution attempts like so:

```
"bootstrap-offcanvas": "git://github.com/yagudaev/Bootstrap-Offcanvas.git#d7249875c049b6cce3c8fbdbda9d7b8ced296030"
```

Also avoid using:

```
git@github.com:yagudaev/Bootstrap-Offcanvas#master
```

It seems to also fail on heroku, but may work locally.